# Ada program calling c functions has problems with interfaces.c.size_t

Tags: c, ada, fftw

I have been working on an Ada project and need to interface with a C library (fftw3).  I used the command

```
gcc -c -fdump-ada-spec -C /usr/local/include/fftw3.h
```

to generate a preliminary binding (some tweaking required).  I was able to get my code and the fftw3_h.ads to compile in gnat.  However, the program crashes with

```
raised STORAGE_ERROR : fftw3_h.ads:733 object too large
```

When I run it through gdb, the code is crashing on a line that defines a version string,

```
fftw_version : aliased char_array (size_t);  -- /usr/local/include/fftw3.h:457
pragma Import (C, fftw_version, "fftw_version");
```

My understanding of this is that Ada is trying to allocate space for the entire string all at once and is basing the storage space on the range of size_t.  However, size_t in this case comes from interfaces.c.size_t which is defined as

```
type size_t is mod 2 ** System.Parameters.ptr_bits;
```

in i-c.ads while for C, size_t is defined as unsigned long in stddef.h.  I am not sure how big 2**ptr_bits is, but I don't see any reason why the definition of size_t in i-c.ads should be expected to be limited to the size of C's unsigned long.  If it is longer than C's unsigned long, then I suspect that the code is trying to create an array that uses more memory than I have.  I have tried to just use interfaces.c.unsigned_long instead of size_t, but Ada does not like the type mismatch (which I should have know).

At this point, I have two questions.  Firstly, is my understanding of the problem close (this is my first experience with interfacing to between Ada and C).

Secondly, assuming my understanding is correct, is there a way around the problem or do I need to take a completely different approach?

Answer (score 4):

Thank you everybody.  Simon's answer really helped.  One problem is that fftw_version[] is set in the C code for fftw, not by me, and I cannot guarantee that the procedure will be called before something in the fftw library needs it (fftw3_h.ads is elaborated before any of my code).  I also found an old FFTW_Ada binding online from 2004 by Stephen J. Sangwine.  While I could not get his code to work, I combined how he dealt with the version string with Simon's suggestion and created a function that returns the string when needed by something else in the fftw library.

```
function FFTW_Version return String is
    tmp_version : aliased char_array(size_t) ;
    pragma Import(C, tmp_version, "fftw_version");
 begin
    return To_Ada(tmp_version, Trim_Nul => True) ;
 end FFTW_Version;
```

This gives me something that produces the string when needed, but does not make assumptions about the size of the string (which the FFTW_Ada code did).  This compiles and works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you understand the size of the array you are trying to create with

```
fftw_version : aliased char_array (size_t);  -- /usr/local/include/fftw3.h:457
```

This line does not simply state that the array fftw_version is indexed by the type size_t, it also specifies that the array indices span the range of 0..2**32, which apparently is too large for your hardware to handle.
What array size do you really want here? For instance, if you want an array of 100 characters you should specify

```
fftw_version : aliased char_array(size_t range 0..99);
```

Comment: No, this is imported; there is no corresponding object in the Ada source. It’s going to be nul-terminated, so get contents by e.g. `To_Ada (fftw_version, Trim_Nul => True)` (which is the default).

Comment: I had originally left that part of the specification unchanged, so what I stated in the question was automatically generated by gcc from fftw3.h.  When I stepped through the result in gdb, it threw an exception at the line before the 'pragma Import', as if it was allocating space first, before importing the contents from C.

Comment: Seeing the syntax `fftw_version : aliased char_array (size_t);` looked weird to me, I always feel that an actual range shall be declared. It surprises me that it could compile without an actual range or `size_t'range`.

Answer (score 3):

To quote [the LRM](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3.html#p43):

> The types int, short, long, unsigned, ptrdiff_t, size_t, double, char, wchar_t, char16_t, and char32_t correspond respectively to the C types having the same names.

Regardless of how the actual definition looks like, you can trust the compiler to comply to the LRM, so Ada's `size_t` will, in fact, have the exact same size as C's.

That being said, your error stems from the fact that you get a stack overflow when allocating `size_t'Last` bytes for the array. I searched the `fftw3.h` header for a definition of `fftw_version` which you're trying to wrap, but I couldn't find any, so for a more detailed answer, you need to show the code you're wrapping. Most probably you want to use `chars_ptr` instead from [Interfaces.C.Strings](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3-1.html) to wrap strings from C – its conversion methods take care of getting the string length by searching for the null terminator.

Comment: Thanks for that info.  I will try to work it out as you suggest and post back here in a day or so.  As for the the location of fftw_version in fftw3.h, it is the result of a large macro (FFTW_DEFINE_API(X, R, C)) which gets expanded generate three versions of the entire API, one each for single, double, and long double precision.  So, 'FFTW_EXTERN const char X(version)[]' gets expanded to 'extern const char fftw_version[]' in C, and is converted as I described by the gcc -fdump-ada-spec command.

Comment: But it’s imported! There should be no space allocated in the Ada source file that does the importing, any more than in the C `extern const char fftw_version[]`.

Comment: @SimonWright You're right. Declaration and error message seemed to make it obvious what happens that I didn't properly think about it. Perhaps the compiler still includes the check leading to the Storage_Error even though the variable is imported?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me it’s likely to be what you’re doing with it. This isn’t a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE), because it works for me :-)

bartels.adb:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;
procedure Bartels is
   fftw_version : aliased char_array (size_t);  -- /usr/local/include/fftw3.h:457
   pragma Import (C, fftw_version, "fftw_version");
   V : constant String := To_Ada (fftw_version, Trim_Nul => True);
begin
   Put_Line (V);
end Bartels;
```

bartels_c.c:

```
const char fftw_version[] = "the version";
```

Compile the C file, build the Ada with

```
$ gnatmake bartels.adb -largs bartels_c.o
```

and run

```
$ ./bartels 
the version
```

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing several helpful answers, @Jim Rogers points out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55033956/230513) that the elaboration of an object of `size_t` might exceed available memory. @Simon Wright observes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55041745/230513) and illustrates [here](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-1.html#p38) that no space need be allocated for an imported object. Indeed, the [`Import`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-1.html#p38) aspect, implied by the corresponding [*pragma*](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-J-15-5.html), specifies the following dynamic semantics:

> Notwithstanding what this International Standard says elsewhere, the elaboration of a declaration with a True Import aspect does not create the entity. Such an elaboration has no other effect than to allow the defining name to denote the external entity.

The following complete example, illustrates the aspect corresponding to the pragma shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55048145/230513) in the `function` by @C. Bartels:

console:

```
$ gprclean -q ; gprbuild -q && ./bartels 
Versioni 1.2.3
```

bartels.gpr:

```
project Bartels is

   for Languages use ("Ada", "C");
   for Main use ("bartels.adb");

end Bartels;
```

bartels.adb:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces.C;

procedure Bartels is

   function Get_Version return String is
      version : Interfaces.C.char_array(Interfaces.C.size_t)
         with Import => True, Convention => C;
   begin
      return Interfaces.C.To_Ada(version, Trim_Nul => True) ;
   end Get_Version;

 begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Get_Version);
end Bartels;
```

version.c:

```
const char version[] = "Versioni 1.2.3";
```

As an aside, some confusion may have arisen as this example works with `GNAT Community 2018` but fails with `GNAT GPL 2017`:

```
$ gprclean -q ; gprbuild -q && ./bartels 
raised STORAGE_ERROR : bartels.adb:7 object too large
```